# Matrix (geometric sum) orbit problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, computability, decision-theory

Is the following algorithmic problem known to be decidable/undecidable?

Input: an element $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, and a subgroup $H \leqslant \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Decide: whether there exists an integer $k>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{v} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k} \mathbf{A}^i \right) \in H \, .
\end{equation}

Comment: I believe you may be able to reduce to [Skolem's problem](http://www.tucs.fi/publications/attachment.php?fname=TR683.pdf), which I believe is known to be decidable for $n = 2$, but unknown for higher dimensions